# How do I get my buttons to be in the available space? flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

You can see that there is plenty of space between the image and those buttons. What I want to do is get those buttons in that space. I tried using `positioned()` but it didn't do what what I wanted.

Here's my code:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xffCB2E2E),
          title: const Center(child: Text('MENU')),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 510,
                    width: 510,
                    child: Image.asset('images/drawing.png'),
                  ),
                ),
                
                ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 74, 177, 77),
                      onPrimary: Colors.white,
                      minimumSize: Size(150, 45)),
                  onPressed: () {
                    print('hehe');
                  },
                  child: Text('click here'),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 74, 177, 77),
                      onPrimary: Colors.white,
                      minimumSize: Size(150, 45)),
                  onPressed: () {
                    print('hehe');
                  },
                  child: Text('click here'),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 74, 177, 77),
                      onPrimary: Colors.white,
                      minimumSize: Size(150, 45)),
                  onPressed: () {
                    print('hehe');
                  },
                  child: Text('click here'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

what should I do if I want those buttons to lay in that empty space instead? I think that is probably because of the size of that image but if that's the case I also need the image to be at least that big to look decent, so is there anyway to overlay the buttons on the image without covering completely if needed?

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the height of the sizedbox with the image as child, to fit the image properly, you can use a FittedBox, so the image won't be distorted:

```
SizedBox(
  width: 510,
  height: 350, //example
  child: FittedBox(
    clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
    child: Image(),
  ),
),
```

edit: you need to add `clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,` so that the image won't render outside its borders

Answer (score 0):

You have added a SizedBox of height 510. Remove that and use expanded

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xffCB2E2E),
          title: const Center(child: Text('MENU')),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
           height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child:Center(
                    child: Image.asset('images/drawing.png'),
                ),
               ),
                
                ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 74, 177, 77),
                      onPrimary: Colors.white,
                      minimumSize: Size(150, 45)),
                  onPressed: () {
                    print('hehe');
                  },
                  child: Text('click here'),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 74, 177, 77),
                      onPrimary: Colors.white,
                      minimumSize: Size(150, 45)),
                  onPressed: () {
                    print('hehe');
                  },
                  child: Text('click here'),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 74, 177, 77),
                      onPrimary: Colors.white,
                      minimumSize: Size(150, 45)),
                  onPressed: () {
                    print('hehe');
                  },
                  child: Text('click here'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: yes but as I add more butons and space between them using sized box() the image keeps getting smaller. I think there is more empty space in that 510x510 box so can I place elements over it or something? or do something from which I can add more elemrnts without making the image smaller?

Comment: If you wish to place elements above the image take a look at stack. Or if you wish to make the image bigger you can use fit: Boxfit.cover. This will take the entire space of the parent widget. Remove the center widget and add image dire8to expanded to see the difference